# Server Fault 10k Challenge - Keep Track of Your Progress

Tags: app, website

[image]

### About

At the beginning of the year, a group of people [made an agreement](http://thenubbyadmin.com/2011/01/04/a-call-to-all-community-minded-sysadmins-join-the-serverdault-10000-point-challenge/) to each try to earn 10k rep. on Server Fault in the next year. This webpage is designed to make it easy to view progress and track their reputation over the course of the year.

#### License

MIT License

#### Download

http://challenge.meta.so/

#### Platform

Any modern web browser with JavaScript enabled.

### Contact

I can be reached at `admin@quickmediasolutions.com`.

### Code

Written in JavaScript using jQuery.

Answer (score 3):

Status update from Jacob:

I had larger block of IPs added to my account which made the old ones null routed. I fixed the issues and challenge.meta.so is back in business!